# How do I add all of these prime numbers?

Tags: python

I am using python and trying to make a function in which it will generate all PRIME numbers from 1 to 1000, and then add up all of the prime numbers. So far, I have made it to where all of the prime numbers are printed, but I am confused on how to add them up. Here is my code:

```
lower = 0
upper = 1000

for num in range(lower, upper + 1):
   # all prime numbers are greater than 1
   if num > 1:
       for i in range(2, num):
           if (num % i) == 0:
               break
       else:
           print(num)
```

Comment: Just collect them in a list and take sum of elements of the list.

Comment: @tushaR  sorry I just started python, how do you do that? sorry for wasting time lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved in many ways, but I am presenting you two of them:

**1.) Use a list** :

In my case I named it `The_list()`. It stores all values if a prime number. For that I used `.append()` function. And then sum up all the values stored using `sum()` function.

```
lower = 0
upper = 1000
The_list = []

for num in range(lower, upper + 1):
   # all prime numbers are greater than 1
   if num > 1:
       for i in range(2, num):
           if (num % i) == 0:
               break
       else:
           print(num)
           The_list.append(num)
print(sum(The_list))
```

**2.) Use a variable instead**:

```
lower = 0
upper = 1000
total = 0

for num in range(lower, upper + 1):
   # all prime numbers are greater than 1
   if num > 1:
       for i in range(2, num):
           if (num % i) == 0:
               break
       else:
           print(num)
           total = total + num
print(total)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write a function called get_total, which will return the sum of the prime numbers. This can be done as following:

```
def get_total(lower, upper):
    total = 0
    for num in range(lower, upper + 1):
        if num > 1:
            for i in range(2, num):
                if (num % i) == 0:
                    break
            else:
                total += num
    return total

total_value = get_total(0,1000)
print(total_value)
```

By doing this, you can reuse this function and write any values for the lower and upper numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `total_sum` variable with initializing it to `0` and then add the prime number in the `num` variable into it:

```
lower = 0
upper = 1000
total_sum = 0
for num in range(lower, upper + 1):
   # all prime numbers are greater than 1
   if num > 1:
       for i in range(2, num):
           if (num % i) == 0:
               break
       else:
           print(num)
           total_sum += num
print("Sum of the Prime numbers: {}".format(total_sum))
```

**OUTPUT:**

> 2
> 3
> 5
> .
> .
> .
>
> 983
> 991
> 997
> Sum of the Prime numbers: 76127

Comment: sum is a built-in function in python. Use of sum as the variable name might be confusing to a reader that doesn't know the name is overridden.

Answer (score 1):

Just create an empty list before the loop, then when you determine which numbers are prime, append them to the list, and at the end call `sum()`

```
lower = 0
upper = 1000
primes=[]

for num in range(lower, upper + 1):
   # all prime numbers are greater than 1
   if num > 1:
       mods = [(num % i == 0) for i in range(2, num-1)]
       if any(mods):
           break
       else:
           primes.append(num)
   else:
       continue

print(sum(primes))
```